# How to make a torus stay in a piercing hole while it moves aggressively

Tags: animation, armature, bones, constraints, vertex-groups

Can someone help me figure out how to animate a cube with a piercing hole and an inserted torus stay in place while the cube wiggles, scales and moves?

The image is showing the cube (shaped as a nose) the torus as a pendant (the pendant is comprised of two moving parts). each nostril has a set of separate parented bones. The pendant has three bones, a tiny one inside the piercing hole, the next two I have directly extruded from here. I want the nose to look as one that breaths and wiggles like jello. every time I use the wiggle bone fun it goes nuts. haven't figures it out. I want the droplet(the actual pendant) to use the wiggle bone too so it has the physical back and forth of the gravitating pull, I've applied it to the single bone affecting the droplet and it goes nuts. Also I want to rotate the entire cube so the torus and attached droplet moves with it.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: what did you try so far? and screenshots are faaaar better than making photos from screen and posting here. Maybe you should explain more clear what you want to have (maybe some hand drawn stuff would help)

Comment: How about a render

Comment: great, thanks! But at the former picture i saw bones "in your cube". Is is right that your cube not only scales and moves but you want also complicated movement "inside" the cube? and do you want a rigid body animation?

Comment: each nostril has a set of separate parented bones. The pendant has three bones, a tiny one inside the piercing hole, the next two I have directly extruded from here. I want the nose to look as one that breaths and wiggles like jello. every time I use the wiggle bone fun it goes nuts. haven't figures it out. I want the droplet(the actual pendant) to use the wiggle bone too so it has the physical back and forth of the gravitating pull, I've applied it to the single bone affecting the droplet and it goes nuts. Also I want to rotate the entire cube so the torus and attached droplet moves with it.

Comment: maybe you should copy this comment in your question so everybody has a good explanation what you want to have ;)

Comment: did you ever tried it with rigid body constraint...? maybe type point?

Comment: I am trying the Limit location bone constraint, it kinda works but the wiggle bone disconnects and sends the droplet everywhere. I have given the middle bone of the pendant an inverse kinematic constraint targeting the armature and selecting the droplet pendant, chain length 2,  this works fine but I haven't figured parameters . should I give bones to the piercing hole?